# How can I change Maximum segment lifetime in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sockets, tcp-ip

How can I change maximum segment lifetime in Ubuntu 14.04?
there is no net.inet.tcp.msl there
The problem is that I need my TCPsockets to live more than 240 seconds..

Comment: "there is no net.inet.tcp.msl  there"? Are,you sure?! My manual shows "msl": http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man4/tcp.4freebsd.html

Comment: i'm sure that there is no msl there

Comment: The default TCP timeout is 600 seconds, not 240. If you are getting connection timeouts, then there is likely a problem with the software you're using that shows you this problem, or your network connection.

Comment: I'm not getting connection timeouts. I've opened socket and started to make http sessions. After 240 seconds it is not working any more..

Answer (score 1):

The Maximum Segment Lifetime value is used to determine the TIME_WAIT interval (2*MSL)

Try to check this value with commands below:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
```

edit `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout`

and change default value. Once you have modified your `sysctl.conf` file with the above required settings, you can reload the configuration and make it permanent, by the below command.

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: No, that haven't helped... I've checked that before. Maybe the problem is with OMNeT++ where this time is hard-coded for tcp sockets.

Comment: fin timeout and time wait timeout are not the same thing.

Comment: @c4f4t0r true, but the Linux tcp implementation is far from RFC standard. If you look at the code, the tcp_fin_timeout is the dominant variable here, provided it is less than a hardcoded value of 60s. *shrug* See net/ipv4/tcp.c